# Html5 image Pixelation load

Tags: javascript, html

In my website, images are loaded from top to bottom, how can I change it so the images will load in Pixelation, like on Google Maps when are you zooming in?

Comment: Use a progressive jpg?

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: Google Maps just loads other data when zoomed in, use progressive jpeg as already mentioned

Comment: I understand Google Maps just loads other data when zoomed in, it was just an example to understand what I mean. How to work with progressive jpeg?

Comment: You can save a jpeg as progressive in Photoshop, Gimp and others (save for web?)

Comment: http://peteschuster.com/2013/01/saving-jpegs-for-the-web-setting-photoshop-up-for-progressive-jpegs/

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GIMP/Saving_as_JPEG "Progressive:
Selecting Progressive will change the encoding to display the image at increasingly higher quality levels until the image is fully loaded. Progressive encoding also benefits the image's compression.
Leaving this option unchecked will switch to Standard encoding, where the image is displayed in rows from top to bottom."

Comment: Can you give an example of an img tag that you use to load an image?

Comment: what is the actual usage?

Comment: You may also want to check https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/hub/blogs/srcset-attribute-solving-responsive-image-dilemma

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or if you want a pixelating/rendering blur, you could look here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/jmperezperez.com/medium-image-progressive-loading-placeholder/amp/

> Here is what is going on:
>
> 1. Render a div where the image will be displayed. Medium uses a  with a padding-bottom set to a percentage, which corresponds to the aspect ratio of the image. Thus, they prevent reflows while the images are loaded since everything is rendered in its final position. This has also been referred to as intrinsic placeholders.
> 2. Load a tiny version of the image. At the moment, they seem to be requesting small JPEG thumbnails with a very low quality (e.g. 20%). The markup for this small image is returned in the initial HTML as an , so the browser starts fetching them right away.
> 3. Once the image is loaded, it is drawn in a . Then, the image data is taken and passed through a custom blur() function You can see it, a bit scrambled, in the main-base.bundle JS file. This function is similar, though not identical, to StackBlur‘s blur function. At the same time, the main image is requested.
> 4. Once the main image is loaded, it is shown and the canvas is hidden.
>
> All the transitions are quite smooth, thanks to the CSS animations applied.

An example fromo the page:

```
<figure name="7012" id="7012" class="graf--figure graf--layoutFillWidth graf-after--h4">
  <div class="aspectRatioPlaceholder is-locked">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-fill" style="padding-bottom: 66.7%;"></div>
    <div class="progressiveMedia js-progressiveMedia graf-image is-canvasLoaded is-imageLoaded" data-image-id="1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg" data-width="2000" data-height="1333" data-scroll="native">
      <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/freeze/max/27/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg?q=20" crossorigin="anonymous" class="progressiveMedia-thumbnail js-progressiveMedia-thumbnail">
        <canvas class="progressiveMedia-canvas js-progressiveMedia-canvas" width="75" height="47"></canvas>
        <img class="progressiveMedia-image js-progressiveMedia-image __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" data-src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1800/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1800/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg">
        <noscript class="js-progressiveMedia-inner">&lt;img class="progressiveMedia-noscript js-progressiveMedia-inner" src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1800/1*sg-uLNm73whmdOgKlrQdZA.jpeg"&gt;</noscript>
    </div>
  </div>
</figure>
```

Or you could check out this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jmperez/pen/yYjPER) That JMPerez set up, in an atempt to recreate the effect himself.

I'm sorry about my first answer if its not what you were looking for.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: No, I didn't, not a JS guy. Thanks for fixing it though.